# RxSwit - driver from observable ignoring errors

Tags: swift, rx-swift, rx-cocoa

Let's say I have some view initally filled with some data. Than I fetch data over network and want to update view with this updated data.

At this point I want to create Driver from this observable to drive UI elements. However in case of error in observable I don't want to do anything, as the view has already some data so I just want to ignore such error. asDriver() function wants to define what should be done in case of error. Is it ok to do it like this:

```
let dataUpdated: Observable<DataItem> = ...

let driver = dataUpdated.asDriver(onErrorDriveWith: Driver<DataItem>.empty())
```

?

Answer (score 5):

As suggested the solution could be to use `.filter()`. I imagine something like this will solve your problem:

```
extension Observable {
    func asDriverIgnoringErrors() -> Driver<E> {
        return self.map { $0 as E? }
            .asDriver(onErrorJustReturn: nil)
            .filterNil()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you not using `catchErrorJustReturn(DataItem())` ?

Comment: Beacause I don't want to fill view with empty data when errror occures.

Comment: You can use filter or scan opperator to prevent that.

Comment: Because Driver force you also to observe on main thread and Shares side effects (share(replay: 1, scope: .whileConnected)) in addition to never emit an error.  https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/master/Documentation/Traits.md#rxcocoa-traits

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
extension ObservableType {
    public var asDriverSkippingErrors: Driver<Element> {
        return map { Optional($0) }
            .asDriver(onErrorJustReturn: nil)
            .unwrap()
    }
}
```